# How is it that Maxim, Lyudmila, and Diana have three Bubuki amongst them?

Tags: bubuki-buranki

Maxim has the heart of Zampaza; Lyudmila has the right arm; and Diana has the left arm. Given that they are full siblings (as far as I know), and that Bubuki are passed lineally from parent to child, how is it that they received three Bubuki from their two parents? Did one of their parents have multiple Bubuki?

Answer (score 1):

The character biographies on the show's official website (http://bbkbrnk.com/character/04/) provide an explanation for this unusual state of affairs.

- Maxim: 「ブランキ“ザンパザ”の「心臓」を父親から受け継いでいる。」 ― that is, he inherited Zampaza's heart from his father.
- Lyudmila: 「ザンパザの右手にあたるブブキ“シュヴェドッカ”を母親から受け継いでいる。」 ― she inherited Zampaza's right arm from her mother.
- Diana: 「母の双子の妹（叔母）の死後、主人無しとなっていたザンパザの左手にあたるブブキ“ズヴョズダチカ”を受け継いでいる。」 ― hers is the weird case. Her mother's younger sister passed away (presumably without any descendants), so Zampaza's left arm took Diana (her former master's niece) as its master instead.